# How do you uninstall the nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall, cuda

I have tried to updated nvidia drivers by several methods and it became a mess. Containers that I could run before are not runnable anymore (with the message unsatisfied condition cuda >- 12.3 )

To add to the problem I do not remember the order of the methods I have used. I have applied `apt-get install nvidia-container-toolkit`, I have also used the "Software & Updates" application in the panel "Additional drivers" and have changed the radio button there several times.

So I am thinking it might be better to uninstall the driver completely and start again.

I have searched and it seems there are several methods depending on how you installed the drivers but since I dont remember, what is a good method to uninstall the driver and then install an appropriate again (my card is GTX 1060)

Answer (score -1):

### Remove anything about NVIDIA

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Warning: autoremove may remove some dependencies of other softwares! Take care of the command!

### Install NVIDIA driver

#### Search for your driver

```
apt search nvidia
```

#### Select one driver (the last one is a decent choice)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx
```

#### Reboot

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

#### Test the driver

```
nvidia-smi
```

Comment: [Procedures of reinstalling NVIDIA driver, CUDA and cuDNN](https://github.com/deeperlearner/linux-recipes/blob/master/notes/gpu_setup.md)